# Asp.Net Core Web Application Static Files Gives 404 on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404

I have created a web application using .net core. I have successfully get it running on Windows and Mac. However I get 404 on all my static files on Linux. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and my startup.cs is like this.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose());
}
```

Any idea how to get it running on Linux?

Comment: Are you getting 404s on dynamic files?

Comment: @MartinBrown I have web api and a single page web application. Api endpoints works fine. I get 200 on js folder however, I cannot get anything under content and scripts folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out directories are **case sensetive**.
The app was not able to resolve content/bootstrap.css. However, Content/bootstrap.css was resolving. So I renamed the folders and files accordingly and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is important to set WorkingDirectory to folder where dll files exists. Or run 'dotnet' command from folder where dll files exists.