# Static Files Cannot be Found After Publishing to Linux on ARM

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I got an Web-API project, based on ASP.NET Core 2.1. This Web-API has to deliver static files from the default `wwwroot` folder. This works fine with the code below (from Startup.cs) on my Windows machine.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMvc()
        .UseStaticFiles();
    }
}
```

But when I publish the project for Linux on ARM (`dotnet publish -r linux-arm`) and pushing it to the test system, the static files cannot be retrieved by the browser. The Server returns always HTTP 404, no matter how the files are named and of course I respect upper and lower case on Unix systems, so it should not be realted to [Asp.Net Core Web Application Static Files Gives 404 on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523916).

The wwwroot dir content is readable by the server process. I tested this by using `File.ReadAllText(<full path to file in wwwroot>)`.

The server only runs on localhost and therefore the project does not use other servers, like ngingx.

Comment: I had this exact same problem but the solution for me was to rename my Index.html to index.html. Linux seems more sensitive about the case of the file and I couldn't figure out how to set the default pages for Kestrel on linux.

Comment: @Quintonn Yes, the file systems used on Unix systems are (normally) case sensitive. But that was not the problem in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found out, what I did wrong. I started the Web-API by using the full path. Instead, I had to switch to the application directory first.

Working:

```
cd /home/myuser/testapp
./testapp
```

**Not** working:

```
/home/myuser/testapp/testapp
```

I did not change anything else and I can reproduce this, so switching to the app dir first, seems to be a must.

Comment: For future me: If you are running un'Publish'ed code, then workdir should be where *.csproj is located, meanwhile compiled artifact sits in `./bin/{Debug|Release}/net5.0/{MyAssembly}.dll`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running your web application as a systemd service, you'll need to add the `WorkingDirectory` parameter

```
[Unit]
Description=Service Description
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/parent_of_wwwroot
ExecStart=/path/to/dotnet /path/to/app
SyslogIdentifier=servicename
Restart=Always
User=serviceuser
Environment=DOTNET_ROOT=/path/to/parent_of_dotnet

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```